# DialogFlow Required Parameters Lifespan

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to set up the intent with the required parameters. Intent will ask user input if the required parameters are missing. If users didn't input the parameters for the few times, it will be fallback to failure intent. However, I found that there is no lifespan for required parameters but only in follow-up intent. May I know how to implement this behavior? Thanks.